# Create a dictionary from a csv with variable length entries

Tags: python, csv, parsing, dictionary

I have a CSV with with 8 keys.  Each key contains a list of a variable length for its values.  I used csv.DictWriter to create the csv, now I want to read in the csv into a dictionary.  I've poured through the docs on csv.DictReader and csv.reader and this is what I've come up with:

```
def ReadCSVasDict(csv_file):
with open(csv_file) as file:
    reader= csv.reader(file)
    DataTree= {"Class":[],"ClassID":[],"Ship":[],"ShipID":[],"Range":[],"RangeID":[],"AOB":[],"AOBID":[]}
    keys= list(DataTree.keys())
    for rowIndex, row in enumerate(reader):
        if rowIndex != 0:
            DataTree[keys[rowIndex-1]]= row[rowIndex-1]

ReadCSVasDict("DataTree.csv")
```

The first row of the CSV are the keys (which is why I skip row 0) and this ALMOST works, but I can't figure out how to parse through the entries while preserving their type since DictWriter converts everything to string.  How can I read in the csv AND extract the type of each element in each list?

Sample data looks like this:

```
Class,ClassID,Ship,ShipID,Range,RangeID,AOB,AOBID
"['Unknown', 'Sailboat']",,,,,,,
,"[1, 2]",,,,,,
,,"[['Unknown 1'], ['Sail 1', 'Sail 2', 'Sail 3']]",,,,,
,,,"[[11], [21, 22, 23]]",,,,
,,,,"[[[1000]], [[500, 1000], [1000], [500, 2000]]]",,,
,,,,,"[[[111]], [[211, 212], [221], [231, 232]]]",,
,,,,,,[],
,,,,,,,[]
```

with the code that generated it:

```
def WriteDictasCSV(csv_file, dataDict):
    with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as file:
        fieldnames = ["Class","ClassID","Ship","ShipID", "Range","RangeID","AOB","AOBID"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for key in dataDict:
            writer.writerow({key: dataDict[key]})
sampleDict= {"Class":["Unknown", "Sailboat"],"ClassID":[1,2],"Ship":
[["Unknown 1"],["Sail 1","Sail 2","Sail 3"]],
"ShipID":[[11],[21,22,23]],"Range":[[[1000]],[[500,1000],[1000],
[500,2000]]],"RangeID":[[[111]], [[211,212],[221],[231,232]]],"AOB":
[],"AOBID":[]}

WriteDictasCSV("DataTree.csv", sampleDict)
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data that's representative of the data types you want to preserve?

Comment: "I have a CSV with with 8 keys. Each key contains a list of a variable length" i don't understand

Comment: @andrew_reece: Yes.  Here is a sample dictionary:

sampleDict= {"Class":["Unknown", "Sailboat"],"ClassID":[1,2],"Ship":[["Unknown 1"],["Sail 1","Sail 2","Sail 3"]],
"ShipID":[[11],[21,22,23]],"Range":[[[1000]],[[500,1000],[1000],[500,2000]]],
"RangeID":[[[111]], [[211,212],[221],[231,232]]],"AOB":[],"AOBID":[]}

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what's meant by variable length. Could you please post a sample/snippet csv (essentially of the input)?

Comment: @Sid I mean for each value in "Class" there will be a list of "Ship"s.  Each "Ship" will have several "Range"s assiated with them.  The end result dictionary that I will use to populate a tkinter Treeview with several "Class" of "Ship"s at varying "Range"s and "AOB"s (angle on the bow).

Does that help?

Comment: @DrewWilkins example data is helpful, but best included as an edit to your actual post, instead of as a comment.

Comment: @andrew_reece Thanks.  I'm new to stackoverflow.  I've updated the question.  Thank you for the pointers in posting etiquette.

Comment: @DrewWilkins I can't seem to reproduce the sample dictionary you provided in an earlier comment (ignoring type). Could you please confirm if the data and code snippet are accurate?

Comment: @Sid I can confirm unfortunately.  I'll try posting the sampleDict in the original question.